# How to derive apparent power formula for three phase AC system?

Tags: three-phase, reactive-power, apparent-power, real-power

I know that the total power output of a three phase system is √3 EI cosØ
Where E and I are the line voltage and line current.

Now my question is how can one derive the apparent power equation i.e.. √3 EI
 from the totalpower equation  √3 EI cosØ ?

Comment: I don't get it, you already wrote both formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I introduce, the power triangle: -

[image]